# what is the wrong of php symbols

Tags: php, javascript

I have the  symbol question,
echo the javascript,
`dhxGrid.attachFooter("")` => is function
`dhxGrid.attachFooter("<input type='button' name='export' id='export' value='Add' onclick='taf_add_wins()'>,,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan")`
the symbol `""` and `''` between them, 
could you help to correct the syntax
thank you

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">dhxGrid.attachFooter("<input type='button' name='export' id='export' value='Add' onclick='taf_add_wins()'>,,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan"); </script>';
```

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript">dhxGrid.attachFooter("<input type='button' name='export' id='export' value='Add' onclick='taf_add_wins()'>,,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan");</script>';

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript nested in HTML nested in PHP is a pain. You have a triple layer of nested languages to deal with. Try to avoid that. Just drop out of PHP code mode.

```
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dhxGrid.attachFooter("<input type='button' name='export' id='export' value='Add' onclick='taf_add_wins()'>,,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan");
    </script>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really need to echo this javascript, you can escape the ' symbols by writing:
`\'`. But as Quentin said its much better to drop javascript out of php.